# Overlapping two sounds in spinner

Tags: android

I'm having trouble with the following:

I have a spinner with different songs in it. In the spinner, users can preview the selected sound. I already developed that part. But my problem is: when I select one song from the list it will play. Then when we select another song from the list, Mediaplayer doesn't stop and plays the previous song also. But what I need is to stop the previous song when a user selects another song.

Here is my code...

```
//set onClickListner to the onItem SelectedListner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            choose_ringtone = (int) id;
           // Toast.makeText(setAlarm.this,"The selected choice is "+ id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String ringtSound = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            //set ringtone options
            switch (ringtSound) {
                case "alarm Sound 1":
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.wake_up);
                    break;
                case "alarm Sound 2":
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.alarm);
                    break;
                case "alarm Sound 3":
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.wake_up_tone);
                    break;
                case "alarm Sound 4":
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.sweet_alarm);
                    break;
                case "alarm Sound 5":
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.morning_alarm);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            if(mp!=null) {
                mp.start();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `switch` statement, you could do something like

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
}
```

I am not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but please make sure that it also follows the tips from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()), specifically:

> It is also recommended that once a MediaPlayer object is no longer being used, call `release()` immediately so that resources used by the internal player engine associated with the MediaPlayer object can be released immediately. Resource may include singleton resources such as hardware acceleration components and failure to call `release()` may cause subsequent instances of MediaPlayer objects to fallback to software implementations or fail altogether. Once the MediaPlayer object is in the End state, it can no longer be used and there is no way to bring it back to any other state.

Comment: Thanks.Its work. I also use isPlaying() to check mediaplayer is running or not. But I used it after the switch case.I think that the case.Any way again thanks for the advice..

Comment: good to hear! [Accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat) is a good way to say thanks around here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,,Before `start Play` call below function.

```
switch (ringtSound) {
                case "alarm Sound 1":
                      stopPlaying() 
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(setAlarm.this, R.raw.wake_up);
                    mp.start();
                    break;   
            }
```

Call the function to stop sound.

```
  private void stopPlaying() {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;
               }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `mp.stop();` before start any sound...